# Cannot find xsd in src/main/resources in unit test on CLI only

Tags: java, spring, gradle, classpath

I have a test XML file that is used in my unit tests, that references a schema which is in `src/main/resources`.  When I run the tests in IntelliJ, the schema in `src/main/resources` is successfully added to the classpath:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin.xsd] in classpath: com/meanwhileinhell/mih/admin/core/spring/jbox-core-admin.xsd
```

However, when I run on my command line with Gradle, it cannot find the XSD, and I get a SAXException:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
'http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin.xsd', because 1) could
not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the
document is not <xsd:schema>.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching
  wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'service-info'.
```

--

```
src
  test
    resources
      - test-service-info.xml
```

**test-service-info.xml**

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin.xsd


<mih:restlet-application id="testApplicationId"
    name="testApplication" matchingMode="2">   <<< Line 16, column 49 is after the `>`
```

--

```
src
  main
    resources
      - mih-core-admin.xsd
```

**mih-core-admin.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin"
    xmlns:core_admin="http://www.meanwhileinhell.com/mih/schemas/spring/core-admin">
```

This isn't a naming issue between `mih-core-admin.xsd` and `core-admin`.  Also, when I add the same xsd to `src/test/resources` and `src/test/resources/spring` it still cannot find it.

Gradle version for both IJ and CLI: 4.10.2

## **EDIT**

I've tried adding the following to the `build.gradle` for the project, but still no file on the classpath:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    resources {
      srcDirs = ['src/test/resources', 'src/main/resources/'] 
    }
  }
}
```

and...

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/test/resources'
      include 'src/main/resources/mih-core-admin.xsd'
    }
  }
}
```

and...

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    output.resourcesDir = "build/resources/main"
  }
}
```

and...

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
```

Also tried using `build/resources/main` rather than `src/main/resources` in above examples.